# How to increase width and height of flex position elements?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following flex elements that can take different widths depending on their content, I want to increase their width and height depending on their previous width or height. For example, I want to add `10px` to the the element with the id of `id_1` regardless of its current of width.

- note: I can just add a width to styles and make it like `300px` to increase it, but I don't want that I want to increase the width depending on the the current width,( `width = previous_width+10` )
- note: I didn't provide the element styles with the previous width value.
- note: I added a background color just to make it easier to understand.
- note: I am using `reactjs`  and this is just a simplification, so answers with react or javascript will be ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
      <div id='id_1'>this should have longer width</div>
      <div id='id_2'>second</div>

      <script>
            console.log(document.getElementById('1'))
      </script>

      <style>
            body {
                  display: flex;
            }

            div {
                  background-color: orange;
                  display: block;
            }

            #id_1 {
                  background-color: red;

            }
      </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll probably need javascript, or if you still want to use css, maybe "calc()" css function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing this you need to get the `width` of the current `element` and add the value you want. For the `width` of the element we have to see their "real" `width`.For more about the width of an element here's the [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_element_offsetwidth.asp).

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('id_2'))
let seconddiv = document.getElementById('id_2')
function increment(value){
  
  seconddiv.style.width = `${(seconddiv.offsetWidth + value*1)}px`
  
}
```

```css
body {
                  display: flex;
            }

            div {
                  background-color: orange;
                  display: block;
            }

            #id_1 {
                  background-color: red;

            }
```

```html
<div id='id_1'>this should have longer width</div>
<div id='id_2'>second</div>

<button onclick="increment(10)">Increase width</button>
```